# how to remove the white space in my navbar?

Tags: html, css

There is some white space in my navbar. I don't know if I should add padding and make it 0px. I copied the code from another website and made some edits but their navbar goes across the whole page.

```html
<title> Local Bakery: Sweet Tooth! </title>
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <marquee>Get free delivery on <s>orders over $50</s> ALL ORDERS!</marquee>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/5NJBbntN/Nude-and-Black-Modern-Bakery-Logo.png" width="75" height="75" alt="logo"> Sweet Tooth
    </div>
    <ul class="navmenu">
      <li><a href="#bread"> Bread </a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="#bagels"> Bagels </a></li>
          <li><a href="#knots"> Knots </a></li>
          <li><a href="#loaf"> Loaves </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#desserts"> Desserts </a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="#babka">Babka</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cake">Cakes and Cheesecake</a></li>
          <li><a href="#churros">Churros</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cinrolls">Cinnamon Rolls </a></li>
          <li><a href="#cookies">Cookies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#donuts">Donuts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#muffins">Muffins</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pie">Pies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#turnovers">Turnovers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#waffles">Waffles</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#others">Filipino Desserts</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="#biko">Biko</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cassava">Cassava Cake</a></li>
          <li><a href="#halo">Halo Halo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#leche">Leche Flan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#puto"> Puto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="bread">
  <h1 id="bread"> Bread </h1>
  <h2 id="bagels"> Bagels </h2>
  <h2 id="knots"> Knots </h2>
  <h2 id="loaf"> Loaves </h2>
</section>
<section class="desserts">
  <h1 id="desserts"> Desserts </h1>
  <h2 id="babka"> Babka </h2>
  <h2 id="cake"> Cakes and Cheesecake </h2>
  <h2 id="churros"> Churros </h2>
  <h2 id="cinrolls">Cinnamon Rolls</h2>
  <h2 id="cookies">Cookies</h2>
  <h2 id="donuts">Donuts</h2>
  <h2 id="muffins">Muffins</h2>
  <h2 id="pie">Pie</h2>
  <h2 id="turnovers">Turnovers</h2>
  <h2 id="waffles">Waffles</h2>
</section>
<section class="filipino">
  <h1 id="others"> Filipino Desserts </h1>
  <h2 id="biko"> Biko </h2>
  <h2 id="cassava">Cassava Cake </h2>
  <h2 id="halo">Halo Halo </h2>
  <h2 id="leche">Leche Flan</h2>
  <h2 id="puto">Puto</h2>
</section>
<section class="about">
  <h1 id="about"> About Us </h1>
</section>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Archivo, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
marquee {
  text-shadow: 4px 1px 0px lightcoral;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #627254;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.banner {
  background: #efbc9b;
  color: #627254;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ffcad4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.navmenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.navmenu a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navmenu li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.navmenu li a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.navmenu li:hover ul.subnav {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 64px;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.navmenu li ul.subnav {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #fae7f3;
  border-radius: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 17px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: lightpink;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #e493b3;
}
```

Comment: Don't add filler text to your question to meet the minimum text requirement. Instead, add actually useful information that could help answerers help you.

Comment: Also, consider using a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so answerers can run your code next to your question. It just makes it a bit easier for others to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `body { margin: 0; }`  or `margin: 0` to the existing CSS rule for `body` to remove the default margin of  `body` in most browsers.

```css
body {
  font-family: Archivo, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
marquee {
  text-shadow: 4px 1px 0px lightcoral;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #627254;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.banner {
  background: #efbc9b;
  color: #627254;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ffcad4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.navmenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.navmenu a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navmenu li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.navmenu li a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.navmenu li:hover ul.subnav {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 64px;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.navmenu li ul.subnav {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #fae7f3;
  border-radius: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 17px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: lightpink;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #e493b3;
}
```

```html
<title> Local Bakery: Sweet Tooth! </title>
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <marquee>Get free delivery on <s>orders over $50</s> ALL ORDERS!</marquee>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/5NJBbntN/Nude-and-Black-Modern-Bakery-Logo.png" width="75" height="75" alt="logo"> Sweet Tooth
    </div>
    <ul class="navmenu">
      <li><a href="#bread"> Bread </a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="#bagels"> Bagels </a></li>
          <li><a href="#knots"> Knots </a></li>
          <li><a href="#loaf"> Loaves </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#desserts"> Desserts </a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="#babka">Babka</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cake">Cakes and Cheesecake</a></li>
          <li><a href="#churros">Churros</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cinrolls">Cinnamon Rolls </a></li>
          <li><a href="#cookies">Cookies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#donuts">Donuts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#muffins">Muffins</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pie">Pies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#turnovers">Turnovers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#waffles">Waffles</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#others">Filipino Desserts</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
          <li><a href="#biko">Biko</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cassava">Cassava Cake</a></li>
          <li><a href="#halo">Halo Halo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#leche">Leche Flan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#puto"> Puto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="bread">
  <h1 id="bread"> Bread </h1>
  <h2 id="bagels"> Bagels </h2>
  <h2 id="knots"> Knots </h2>
  <h2 id="loaf"> Loaves </h2>
</section>
<section class="desserts">
  <h1 id="desserts"> Desserts </h1>
  <h2 id="babka"> Babka </h2>
  <h2 id="cake"> Cakes and Cheesecake </h2>
  <h2 id="churros"> Churros </h2>
  <h2 id="cinrolls">Cinnamon Rolls</h2>
  <h2 id="cookies">Cookies</h2>
  <h2 id="donuts">Donuts</h2>
  <h2 id="muffins">Muffins</h2>
  <h2 id="pie">Pie</h2>
  <h2 id="turnovers">Turnovers</h2>
  <h2 id="waffles">Waffles</h2>
</section>
<section class="filipino">
  <h1 id="others"> Filipino Desserts </h1>
  <h2 id="biko"> Biko </h2>
  <h2 id="cassava">Cassava Cake </h2>
  <h2 id="halo">Halo Halo </h2>
  <h2 id="leche">Leche Flan</h2>
  <h2 id="puto">Puto</h2>
</section>
<section class="about">
  <h1 id="about"> About Us </h1>
</section>
```

Comment: thank youu, it looks a lot better now

Answer (score 1):

That margin is being added in the body of your page.
A good practice is to reset the CSS styles for all elements.

Like this:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

There are different ways to do it, look for information about CSS reset or CSS normalize.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your HTML and CSS, and I noticed some white space. Please refer to the following screenshot:

[image]

By default, the body element has an 8px margin property, which is causing the issue you're seeing. To fix this, you need to set 'margin: 0;' in your body tag.

Here's the updated version of the CSS for the body element.

```css
body {
  font-family: Archivo, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reset your browsers CSS rules/set global css rules before applying new ones.
This may fix the spacing problem as well as the sizing issue of your headlines.
You can refer to this website: https://dev.to/hankchizljaw/a-modern-css-reset-6p3

Comment: thank you!! i decided to just change the h2 to h3 instead.

Comment: As HTML should be semantically correct, this may not be the best solution. But you have to decide this on your own.

Comment: okay, i used h1 and h2. i just changed the font size. h1 is 34px and h2 is 26px